# Rendering JSON from AJAX call in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have an ajax call to fetch information from Flickr API which returns JSON data. I want to display values from JSON data in my view. I do this by editing some innerHTML with jQuery. The problem I am having is that the data is undefined, so it looks like a scoping problem.

photo.js

```
jQuery(function() {
  $('#<%=p[:id]%>').click(function (e) {

    //ajax call to fetch photo info

    var fetch_id = '<%=p[:id]%>';
    var fetch_secret = '<%=p[:secret]%>';  

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/photos/fetch_info',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: { 'id' : fetch_id, 'secret' : fetch_secret },
      success: function(data){

        console.log(data)  //returns Object
        console.log(data.title)  //returns appropriate title

        //edit innerHTML of basic_modal
        $('.basic_modal').html(
          "<div id='modal_image'><%= escape_javascript(image_tag p[:url]) %></div><div id='photo_title'><%=data.title %></div>"
         );

        //load modal
          $('.basic_modal').modal({
          overlayClose:true
        });

      } //end success: function(result)
    });
```

When I print data.title to console, I get the appropriate title. However, when I try to edit HTML and render `<%=data.title %>`, I get an undefined variable/method error.

Any tip on how I can display the data in my modal in the view?

Here is my controller:

```
def fetch_info

  @info = flickr.photos.getInfo(:photo_id => params[:id], :secret=> params[:secret])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @info }
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

You donot need to do this, Because `datatype:JSON` already parse the data

```
$('.basic_modal').html(
          "<div id='modal_image'><%= escape_javascript(image_tag p[:url]) %>
</div><div id='photo_title'><%="+data.title+" %></div>"
         );
```

this might help you

Comment: I addressed this in my problem above. I printed it to console and saw that it returns NULL so I figured it was already parsed. I'll remove it for readability and to avoid confusion.

Comment: `<%="+data.title+"%>` displays the string `+data.title+` in my view, not the actual title.

Comment: The actual value of the title. For example, if I have the following JSON available in the DOM: `{"title":"Cheeseburger"}`, I want to render "Cheeseburger"

Comment: I am a php develper please format your code properly so that i can answer properly

Comment: I think this is more of a Rails question. I appreciate the help though :)

Comment: I figured it out. You were right, I had data.title inside a string.